# Processing Paypal payments with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am looking for a simple library or script that I can use to make payments to PayPal. I downloaded a couple of libraries and they are all very complicated and have tons of features I dont need. I simply want a way to have a button(pay now) and when they click it, they get redirected to paypal, make the payment, and return to my site so I can save the data into the database. Can anyone recommend a good simple library or a tutorial even?

Also is that even still possible with the new PayPal API? Another words do I need to sign up for an API account to make this happen?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

These might not be as simple as you're looking for, but they work very well, are well documented in the code, and the developer is very responsive on the comments as well as here on SO.

http://www.binpress.com/app/paypal-adaptive-payments-pro-payflow-codeigniter-library/140
http://www.binpress.com/app/php-paypal-pro-adaptive-payflow-api-class/612

From what i've worked on, paypal is a pain in the wein, but these libraries help lessen the pain.